# How to store parameters on a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, storage

I'm currently working on a Project which needs to store some values (in the form of parameter lists). These values can be of some defined types (uint32, char[], ...).
Now I would like to make these parameter lists persistent, meaning I want to load and save them.
I also want to be able to "download" them to the computer and edit them there, then upload them again to the device which will then use them.

Until now, I have used a simple text file which features Key-Value pairs such as:

```
EnterTime=18.0\n
DisallowTime=3\n
EnterMessage=Hello this is me\n
ExternalPhoneNumber=+1212345678
...
```

Yet, I think that there must be a better approach. Space is not a real problem, but I'm not sure if I want to switch to XML, I don't think that would be a better approach.

Any ideas on this? How do you handle such a situation?

Kind regards
Thomas

Comment: what you actually want, some library to parse this and use values in your computer application? You could simply communicate parameters using a serial port.

Comment: I don't see this as an electronics question.

Comment: Not a real electronics question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML may be a better approach when you want to share your data through web and internet 
or make it inter-operable with another application. If you using a single standalone 
application and you don't have tree like data structure to be stored, My suggestion is to
use simple key value based file that you already came with.

There are ready-made libraries for you to parse your such text files.
Take a look at this:  http://cfgparser.sourceforge.net/

Or you could simply code a recursive decent parser by yourself.

Comment: Alright, I already thought that this might be the most efficient way .. Back to the roots :)